# Политика iptables при отключении интерфейса

Tags: linux, iptables, маршрутизация, nat

Поддерживает ли iptables правила или приоритеты, по которым можно задать действия в случае отключения одного из интерфейсов? Конкретно, необходимо настроить port forwarding так, чтобы в зависимости от порта источника пакет направлялся на один из двух интерфейсов, но в случае отключения одного, все пакеты бы шли на оставшийся интерфейс.

Answer (score 2):

Iptables ничего не знает о состоянии интерфейсов.

В некоторых дистрибутивах (Debian, например), вы можете поставить обработчики, которые будут срабатывать когда интерфейс поднимается или опускается, и менять правила в iptables. Для Debian такие обработчики прописываются в `/etc/network/if-up.d/` и `/etc/network/if-down.d/`.

Answer (score 1):

Нет, так сделать без дополнительного скриптинга не получится.
Сам по себе iptables/netfilter не позволяет описывать никаких условий,
это просто цепочки фильтрации.

Вам нужно или динамически менять правила фильтрации в зависимости
от состояния интерфейсов.